# Execute SSH on running docker container with pass

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile

Helo!
I want to restore my production databse backup into my docker. So, I want to download it inside my container fro external server. Its fails because the ssh password...

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:5.6
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD password
EXPOSE 3306 
COPY ./scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ssh 
COPY  ./ssh /home/mysql/.ssh
```

and my script to download the sql file is

```
completePath=$(ssh -T user@host.ip << EOF
cd /home/data/last/2020*
sourcePath=\$PWD
databaseURI=\`ls gran*\`
sourcePath=\$sourcePath/\$databaseURI
echo \$sourcePath
EOF
)
echo $completePath

scp user@host.ip:/$completePath $PWD
mv database.dmp database.sql
```

The script is working fine outside Docker.
This is de error when I

```
docker run --name database -p 3306:3306  prod-database
```

***Permission denied, please try again.
Received disconnect from host.ip port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Authentication failed.***

Hope you can help me! Tks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' password) ssh -T user@172.22.18.71
```